# how do I add a simulation ID on the Gatling 3.3.1 since the mute option is not available anymore

Tags: scala-gatling

[can not add simulation ID since the mute option is dropped in this version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY04z.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're in interactive mode because you don't specify the option to force the simulation class name.
Please have a look at the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/configuration/#zip-bundle-command-line-options).

Comment: I need to run the same simulation twice and get the number of users for ber simulation reflected on Grafana, In Gatling 2.3.1 we used to add the simulation ID so the Grafana deals with them as deferent simulations but with Gatling 3.3.1 we can't add the simualtion ID so the Grafana returns the first run of the simulation only.
Is there any command that we can use to differentiate between the same simulation running twice.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your original question which was related to the `mute` option being drop because it was actually useless as you're not in interactive mode as soon as you provide the simulation class.

Comment: Thank you
Put do you have any idea If this is doable ?

Comment: Stéphane, do you have any updates on this?